# Storekit User Login Dialog popping up while Transaction delivers content

Tags: ios, background, transactions, download, storekit

StoreKit behaves weird when downloading Apple hosted content and switching from back- to foreground.

When an application enters foreground while a transaction is delivering content (SKDownload) it will repeatedly ask for user credentials.

- User purchases product
- transaction download starts
- user enters background (download still running)
- user enters foreground again (download still running)
- **user will be asked to sign in to iTunes Store**

Per documentation a transaction should not be finished before the downloads completes. The unfinished transaction causes the user to login again (I assume).

**Is anyone experiencing a similar behavior? A user should not be forced to authenticate a transaction that is still active.**

Am I missing something?

Comment: can you post your code,this will happen because of unfinished transactions

Comment: I'm experiencing the same behaviour, does anyone have found a solution?